# Pandas create new column based on first unique values of existing column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, unique

I'm trying to add a new column to a dataframe with only unique values from an existing column. There will be fewer rows in the new column maybe with np.nan values where duplicates would have been.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5], 'b':[3,4,3,4,5]})
df

    a   b
0   1   3
1   2   4
2   3   3
3   4   4
4   5   5
```

Goal:

```
    a   b   c
0   1   3   3
1   2   4   4
2   3   3   nan
3   4   4   nan
4   5   5   5
```

I've tried:

```
df['c'] = np.where(df['b'].unique(), df['b'], np.nan)
```

It throws:  `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (5,) ()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) + [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html)

You can use Pandas methods for masking a series:

```
df['c'] = df['b'].mask(df['b'].duplicated())

print(df)

   a  b    c
0  1  3  3.0
1  2  4  4.0
2  3  3  NaN
3  4  4  NaN
4  5  5  5.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['c'] = np.where(df['b'].duplicated(),np.nan,df['b'])
```

Or:

```
df['c'] = df['b'].where(~df['b'].duplicated(),np.nan)
```

---

```
print(df)
   a  b    c
0  1  3  3.0
1  2  4  4.0
2  3  3  NaN
3  4  4  NaN
4  5  5  5.0
```